# Is this char array returns undefined behavior?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

A classmate had a function like this :

```
char* Func( int a )
{
    if( a == 0 )
        return "yes";
    else
        return "no";
}
```

I know that return a local char* is undefined, but when I asked him he said that since "yes" and "no" wasn't declared as variable it was not undefined behavior.

Who is right? And why?

Comment: It should be `const char *` but beyond that, its acceptable. He's correct; the returned address is still valid and the code otherwise well-formed.

Comment: You answered what I wanted to know in the delete answer. ( That since "yes" is a string literal, it has a static variable lifetime. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no local array here, the code shown is well-defined.

The function just returns a pointer of type `char` and here you are actually just returning a string not a reference to any array.

```
char *func(int a)
{
   char b[10];
   char *p = b;
   if( a == 0)
   return p;
}
```

Here you have an error and I think the compiler will report/warn it since you are returning a reference to a local array.The lifetime of array `b` is just within the `func()` and when you exit the function the array is not more valid.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is working fine, here is what i tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* Func(int a)
{
    if (a == 0)
        return "yes";
    else
        return "no";
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char a[5] = { 0, };
    strcpy(a, Func(0));
    printf("returned %s",a);
    return 0;
}
```

this gave output: `returned yes`

---

and

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* Func(int a)
{
    if (a == 0)
        return "yes";
    else
        return "no";
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char a[5] = { 0, };
    strcpy(a, Func(1));
    printf("returned %s",a);
    return 0;
}
```

gave output: `returned no`

Comment: Be cautious that "working fine" is a member of undefined behavior.

Comment: @tia, thanks, here what i have tried to convey is that the behavious is dependant on its usage in the calling function (`main()` in this example) and not the function `Func()` itself, as mentioned in his question.